# How can I set an ASP.Net Core exe.config value from Azure App Service Connection String

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I have a ASP.Net Core 2.2 application, targeting .Net Framework 4.7.2 hosted on Azure App Services. 
I want to use the Azure App Service Connection string to set my connection strings. As I'm targeting .Net Framework, my app has a appname.exe.config file, in which the configuration elements are stored (entity framework being one of them).

When I try to use the connection string, I get an error message "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.".

I have tried these against a normal .Net Framework application and they work perfectly, but I assume because Asp.Net Core uses the out of process EXE file, the connection strings aren't being populated.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Thanks in advance,
David

Comment: How did you read the connection string from .net core? If you define a variable to check the connectionstring value, could you get the expected result?

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework 6, so it reads from there by default. I'm trying to place it in a location that I can set from the Azure App Service Connection string section.

Answer (score 0):

From the above comment, you mentioned you are placing the connection string in a location. I am hoping you placed it in the constructor, Because the Connection String should be passed to your Constructor in Entity Framework 6, so it can read it easily when you are calling that constructor from your code.

You can refer to the below link to see how to handle the connection strings with ASP.NET Core Applications.

[Handle Connection strings in EF6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

You can also refer to this below link on how you can set them in Appsettings.json.

[ASP.Net Core App Settings](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2018/06/12/asp-net-core-settings-for-azure-app-service/)